# Cummulative Time Spent in Specific States

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, aggregate, timedelta

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

[image: Table Headers and Sample Data]

What I would like to do with this data is calculate how much time was spent in specific states, per day. So say for example I wanted to know how long the unit was running today. I would just like to know the sum of the time the unit spent RUNNING: 45 minutes, NOT_RUNNING: 400 minutes, WARMING_UP: 10 minutes, etc.

I know how to summarize the column data on its own, but I'm looking to reference the time stamp I have available to subtract the first time it was on, from the last time it was on and get that measure of difference. I haven't had any luck searching for this solution, but there's no way I'm the first to come across this and know it can be done some how, just looking to learn how. Anything helps, Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: emphasizing martineau's comment: To get helpful feedback quicker, please make sure to provide sample data as text, not image. Also, add some code you have tried, to give others an impression where you start.